# Workflow issue with Incoming email enabled functionality

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

Here is the scenario

A document library, enabled with incoming email settings.
A task list.
When a user sends  a document via email - the document gets added in the document library.

There is a workflow attached to a document library which creates an item in task list.
Task list has a workflow which sends email to Assigned To person on task item creation.

The workflow which is attached to Document Library is working fine as per expectations but workflow attached on task list is not working.

I tried the same with SharePoint 2010 and 2013 workflow but no luck. Used App Step as well.

Any idea how to resolve this issue.

Note: Manually workflows are getting triggered.

Is this because of created by :

**Content Type: Task

Created at 10/27/2017 7:21 AM  by Workflow

Last modified at 10/27/2017 7:21 AM  by Workflow**

Answer (score 0):

Which account is used to trigger the workflow of Document library, if its used by System Account then the Task will be created as System Account.

In sharepoint if the Item is created by System Account then it wont start workflow automatically.

Please check